# SQL output a rank of items given a different maximum rank per item

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, partition

Here is the criteria I am looking for
(1) rank data by region
(2) include top 3 for two regions and top 5 for other region

I am able to get criteria (1) using the query below:

```
select rank() over (partition by region order by sales_score desc) rank_by_region,
       region,
       sales_person
       sales_score
from sales_owner.data
```

If I get three regions (North, South, West). How would I order the rank that the output would include **top 3** for North and South and **top 5** for West?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use a `where` condition with `or`.

```
select region,sales_person,sales_score from
(
select rank() over (partition by region order by sales_score desc) rank_by_region,
       region,
       sales_person
       sales_score
from sales_owner.data
) t
where (region in ('North','South') and rank_by_region <= 3)
or (region = 'West' and rank_by_region <= 5)
```

Comment: This solution is 100% correct. It may be a little more efficient if written as `where rank_by_region <= 3 or (region = 'West' and rank_by_region <= 5)` - although I'd say vkp's solution is more readable, which is an important benefit.